# How to remove gaps from a block of text in MS Word

Tags: blocking, alignment

I copied some text from the internet and when pasted it into the Word file then it produced gaps among many words. I tried "Justify" option, it removes the gaps but it then breaks the block of the text (text is not aligned on the corners). Please help to solve it.

Comment: Can you add a picture of your issue, please?

Comment: How do you want the text to be aligned on both sides, without adding gaps between the words when the line is too short to fit exactly?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you copied and pasted formatting and text. You could consider paste as text only and then format as you require.

I nearly always paste-as-text as too much hidden data copies and often is difficult to remove and adjust formatting the way it's desired.

Word has the paste-text function, but not all programs do this, workaround is to paste into Notepad first then copy that to the desired program.